Wording clarification for remastered powerful shove feat
The remastered rules text for Powerful Shove reads as follows (emphasis mine)

You can push larger foes around with your attack. You can use Aggressive Block or Brutish Shove against a creature up to two sizes larger than you.
When a creature you Shove or knock back with a shield, polearm, or club’s critical specialization effect has to stop moving because it would hit an object, it takes damage equal to your Strength modifier (minimum 1).

The wording is somewhat ambiguous to me. Which is the correct understanding of the text:
"A creature takes damage when you shove it into an object with a

Pole-arm
Shield
Club's critical specialization effect"

or
"A creature takes damage when you shove it into an object with a

Pole-arm's critical specialization effect
Shield's critical specialization effect
Club's critical specialization effect"

Related but pre-remaster

Neither, but the Second is Closer
This ability was buffed as part of the remaster, as a target now takes damage when Shoved or when they are knocked back by one of the listed critical specializations. Originally the damage only occured when a creature was Shoved, "regardless of how you Shoved the creature", but those critical specializations only forced movement and didn't involve a Shove.
Notably this also covers your first interpretation, where Shoves with a polearm or shield would be included as any other Shove, as well as when making a Shove as part of an Aggressive Block or Brutish Shove.

I think this would be clearer if you added a list, e.g.: "Aggressive Block, Brutish Shove, Shove maneuver, shield cris spec, polearm crit spec, club crit spec"

The key is that it now also says "...or knock back"
